# URL encoding and unshortening

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I have some links that I am collecting from a sitemap and twitter. The problem is that some links are in Arabic like this one:

```
https://www.aljazeera.net/videos/2021/3/1/ياقوتيا-مدينة-روسية-يتجمد-فيها-كل-شيء
```

I am trying to unshorten the shortened twitter links and decode the Arabic encoded links to get links that look like this:

```
https://www.aljazeera.net/videos/2021/3/1/%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%82%D9%88%D8%AA%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A9-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D9%8A%D8%AA%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%AF-%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%87%D8%A7-%D9%83%D9%84-%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%A1
```

Comment: And what issue are you facing? [ask]

Comment: So what happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem? When you say "The problem is that some links are in Arabic like this one:", why did that cause a difficulty? Where you say "I am trying to unshorten the shortened twitter links and decode the Arabic encoded links", were you able to write code to unshorten the unshortened twitter links? What part of the code is actually causing difficulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to take a url with odd characters in it, and convert it to the `%XX` format, you can use python's builtin, `urllib`, to decode the link:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> oddlink = 'https://www.aljazeera.net/videos/2021/3/1/ياقوتيا-مدينة-روسية-يتجمد-فيها-كل-شيء'
>>> goodlink = urllib.parse.quote(oddlink)
>>> print(goodlink)
https%3A//www.aljazeera.net/videos/2021/3/1/%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%82%D9%88%D8%AA%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A9-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D9%8A%D8%AA%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%AF-%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%87%D8%A7-%D9%83%D9%84-%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%A1
```

Keep in mind that it will parse the `:` after `https` to `%3A`. You can manually override this:

```
>>> goodlink = goodlink[0:5] + ':' + goodlink[6:]
>>> print(goodlink)
https://www.aljazeera.net/videos/2021/3/1/%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%82%D9%88%D8%AA%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A9-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D9%8A%D8%AA%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%AF-%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%87%D8%A7-%D9%83%D9%84-%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%A1
```

Or, you can add the `:` as a 'safe' character, meaning that `urllib.parse` will ignore it, and leave it be:

```
>>> urllib.parse.quote(oddlink, safe='/:')
```

The `/` is part of the safe characters because it is a very important part of links:

```
https://www.google.com/ #with slash
https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F #without slash
```

The `/` character is included by default in the safe characters, but when changing the safe characters, you need to make sure to include it.